# Can we use Android-Studio Translations Editor for Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Translations editor was very good in dealing with strings and translating it to many languages. I wonder if I could use it for flutter apps.

```
if(yes) {
   tell me how;
}else{
   tell me the best way to translate texts in flutter;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

now I think we couldn't use it.

so, for now, I can use excel to make CSV file of strings and use [flappy_translator package](https://pub.dev/packages/flappy_translator#-readme-tab-) to use it in a flutter app.

if there's a way to use android studio translations editor or there's a better way, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the handy Android Studio [Translation Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor), however it only works with
`strings.xml` in a `res/values` folder in native Android projects, as it seems.

[image]

But I can offer you something similar. I found the Android Studio Plugin `Easy i18n`

Go to **File->Settings->Plugins** (windows) and search for the plugin.
[image]

After Installation, you can work with JSON files, I put them in assets/translations:
[image]

And added the dependency to the whole folder in my **Pubspec.yaml**:

```
  assets:
- assets/translations/
```

And if you open the Editor via **View->Tool Windows->Easy i18n**, you can edit them, very similar to the Android Studio Translation Editor:

[image]

I use the values from the JSON files with the [Easy Localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) plugin.

**Disclaimer**: *I don't think the authors of `Easy i18n` and `Easy Localization` are the same team, at least as I can tell. And I am in no way related to these projects/authors. This is just what worked for me. On my journey, I stumbled across this StackOverFlow post multiple times, so I thought I'd share.*